# Dynamically create Excel template using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, templates, npoi

I have an Excel `.xlsx` template file that I need to dynamically adapt to my needs. It contains only the title row for now, and two of the columns are "placeholder" columns where I need to insert new columns to fit my needs.

The title row might look like this:

```
FirstName | LastName | City | #Modules# | Remarks | #Experts# | Country | Phone
```

The two columns with the `#` are the "placeholder" values - depending on some data I get from the database, I need to replace those single columns with multiple columns - e.g. replace `#Modules#` with three columns, titled `M1`, `M2` and `M3`, and replace `#Experts#` with `Expert 1` and `Expert 2` - so in the end, my Excel should look something like this:

```
FirstName | LastName | City | M1 | M2 | M3 | Remarks | Expert 1 | Expert 2 | Country | Phone
```

I'm trying to achieve this with NPOI v2.2, but haven't been successful as of yet.

Approach #1: I tried using the `IRow.CreateCell` call, but that seems to be *overwriting* existing columns, so when I find `#Modules#` and replace it with my actual module data, I end up having

```
FirstName | LastName | City | M1 | M2 | M3 | Country | Phone
```

and my placeholder for the experts is gone (overwritten by one of the concrete modules).

Code:

```
XSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(templateFileName);

ISheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
IRow firstRow = sheet.GetRow(0);  // title row

// find the #Modules# placeholder - works as expected
ICell cellModule = firstRow.Cells.Find(x => x.StringCellValue == "#Modules#");
int moduleIndex = cellModule.ColumnIndex;   

List<string> listOfModule = new List<string>(new[] { "M1", "M2", "M3" });

foreach (string module in listOfModule)
{
    ICell newCell = firstRow.CreateCell(moduleIndex, CellType.String);
    newCell.SetCellValue(module);

    moduleIndex += 1;
}
```

This overwrites the existing cells in the title row and thus "destroys" part of my template file.....

Approach #2: I tried to use the `.Insert()` method for inserting a cell:

```
foreach (string module in listOfModule)
{
    // create a new cell, set its value
    ICell newCell = new XSSFCell(firstRow as XSSFRow, new CT_Cell());
    newCell.SetCellValue(module);

    // insert new cell into title row
    firstRow.Cells.Insert(moduleIndex, newCell);

    moduleIndex += 1;
}
```

but it this case, the cell doesn't seem to actually get **inserted**, my title row doesn't change at all and just stays as it was in the beginning.

Any ideas?? The documentation for NPOI is a bit ...... lacking, to say the least.....

Thanks!

Comment: How about making a copy of the row first and later when the operations on  the cells are performed, you can join the results in one, further creating the desired row. I see the `Remarks` column is also missing as per your 1st approach

Comment: I've given up on NPOI and switched to the (commercial) [Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/products/cells/net) library to handle my Excel needs